# Should a form contain an object, or an object the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose I have only one Windows Form for a project. If I have another class that is used to make HTTP requests and handle data, which solution should I use?

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
     private MyObject myObject;
}
```

Or this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private MyForm myForm;
}
```

Comment: It entirely depends on how they interact.

Comment: Since you are actually talking about instances, which are pointers internally, you can do both at the same time.

Comment: both ways works but it depends on the structure and data flow of your solution, more information can help !!

Comment: Use proper `delegates` and `events` as a means of communication between your lower-level (data access or network-related) code and the upper-level UI. **never, ever, ever** tie your code to UI frameworks, especially `System.Windows.Forms.dll` which is a deprecated assembly.

Comment: Hog wash, it is not a deprecated assembly.

Comment: @HansPassant try using any classes from that assembly in WinRT =)

Comment: Try using any WPF classes in a WinRT app.

Comment: @HansPassant they're there, just different namespace ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.aspx)) =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it is not a good idea to have `Form` object in the class. But It depends on the situation.

If your class is responsible for making HTTP calls and handle data that it appears more like a business layer or data access layer object, in that case **it should be independent of UI**.

Imagine if you need to use the same class with your Web application, in that case you can extract out the class in a separate class library and use it in both Web and Desktop applications. But that could only work if your class is independent of UI.  If you have form object in your class then you are **coupling** UI with your logic.

Comment: Great way to look at it. Thank you!!

Comment: @Habib With the most likely exception being a Form that holds a reference to another Form instance :-)